# Pandas dataframe returns nothing when there is only one value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
print(frame.ix[0]['titles'].values)
```

returns nothing instead of printing 'abc' and terminates the program if

```
print(frame)
```

is

```
0    'abc'
```

Comment: Because frame isn't actually a DataFrame. It's a Series - one dimensional. Just take the element at index 0. *`frame.iloc[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

Base on your approach

```
df.ix[0]['titles']
Out[1085]: 'abc'
```

I will using `iloc` since *.ix is deprecated.*

```
df.iloc[0].loc['titles']
Out[1091]: 'abc'
```